# Parse - setting a new PFObject as the value of another new PFObject's key using the REST API

Tags: python, ios, rest, parse-platform

Using the `iOS Parse SDK`, I can successfully create a new `PFObject A` and set it as the value on another new `PFOBject B`:

```
PFObject * objectA = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"objectA"];
[objectA setValue:@"Test Text" forKey:@"text"];

PFObject * objectB = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"objectB"];
[objectB setValue:objectA forKey:@"objectA"];
```

When I perform a `[PFObject saveAll:(NSArray*)objects]`, Parse will generate an `objectId` for the `objectA`, and set it as a pointer value in a key on `objectB`.

How can I do this with the `REST API (PYTHON)`. From the documentation, it appears that I must present the following when passing a pointer as a value on a key for my class `objectB`:

```
{"__type": "Pointer", 
"className": "objectA", 
"objectId":objectA.get('objectId')}
```

However, when I create a new `objectA`, the `objectId` doesn't exist yet.

This is my python code:

```
def generateFakeMessages():
    messageFactory = MessageFactory(retrieveUsers())

    appKeys = {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "XXXX",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "XXXX",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"}

    mList = []
    objectA = messageFactory.fakeMessage()
    arrayOfObjectBs = messageFactory.fakeRecipients()

    mList.append({
             "method": "POST",
             "path": "/1/classes/testMessageClass",
             "body": objectA
           })
    for objectB in arrayOfObjectBs:
        objectB['objectAPointer'] = {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "testMessageClass",
                "objectId": objectA.get('objectId')
                }
        mList.append({
             "method": "POST",
             "path": "/1/classes/recipients",
             "body": objectB
               })

    requests = {"requests":mList}
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()
    connection.request('POST', '/1/batch', json.dumps(requests), appKeys)
    result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
    print result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this question on the Parse forum](https://parse.com/questions/saveall-in-js-makes-an-api-call-per-object), `saveAll:` is using [batches](https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-batch) in the background, if it determines that the object graph has unsaved children it does them in a batch, then uses the results of that to be able to correctly save the parents.

To do this yourself using the REST API you'll need to work out the batches yourself. Batches are limited to 50 create/update/delete operations per batch.

If you have 50 `objectA` instances each with an `objectB` that references it you could do that in 2 batches.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected code using batches. Instead of setting a pointer representation for

```
objectB['message']
```

I set the actual object. Parse sorts out the dependency on upload.

```
def generateFakeMessages():
    messageFactory = MessageFactory(retrieveUsers())

    appKeys = {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "XXXX",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "XXXX",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"}

    mList = []
    objectA = messageFactory.fakeMessage()
    arrayOfObjectBs = messageFactory.fakeRecipients()

    mList.append({
             "method": "POST",
             "path": "/1/classes/testMessageClass",
             "body": objectA
           })
    for objectB in arrayOfObjectBs:
        objectB['message'] = fakeMessage
        mList.append({
             "method": "POST",
             "path": "/1/classes/recipients",
             "body": objectB
               })


    requests = {"requests":mList}
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()
    connection.request('POST', '/1/batch', json.dumps(requests), appKeys)
    result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
    print result
```